# Add up button to PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I can't figure out how I would go about implementing an up button in a `PreferenceScreen`.  An up button displays a caret in your action bar next to your app icon that allows you to navigate the app's hierarchy, more info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

I have a Preference Fragment that displays when my main activity is opened and I can get the up button to display by adding this line " getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);":

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
    .commit();
```

This causes the up button to display in the Preference Fragment, but I only want to show the up button when one of my `PreferenceScreens` is opened, allowing navigation to the main `PreferenceFragment`.

My app is analogous to the main settings app. Only the child screens, like Location Access, that opens from the main Settings app has the up arrow.

[image]

Comment: And what do you want to be shown when you are in the main preferences screen? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: In the main preference screen, I do not want to be shown an up button.    I do not need on because the Main Activity of my app is simply a Preference Fragment.  There is nothing else to the app but this Preference Fragment.  And within this Fragment, I have only one Preference that opens up another Preference Screen. It is on this Preference Screen only, where I want the up button to be displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your complete application is a preferences screen, then you can make your main activity a `PreferenceActivity` and the sub-levels can be fragments. This way the 'up' functionality is going to be by default what you are looking for.

Answer (score 14):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374820/action-bar-home-button-not-functional-with-nested-preferencescreen), I simply added these two code blocks to my Preference Fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference    preference) {
super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);

// If the user has clicked on a preference screen, set up the action bar
if (preference instanceof PreferenceScreen) {
    initializeActionBar((PreferenceScreen) preference);
}

return false;
}
```

And this one:

```
 /** Sets up the action bar for an {@link PreferenceScreen} */
    public static void initializeActionBar(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
    final Dialog dialog = preferenceScreen.getDialog();

    if (dialog != null) {
        // Inialize the action bar
        dialog.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Apply custom home button area click listener to close the PreferenceScreen because PreferenceScreens are dialogs which swallow
        // events instead of passing to the activity
        // Related Issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4611
        View homeBtn = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.home);

        if (homeBtn != null) {
            OnClickListener dismissDialogClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            };

            // Prepare yourselves for some hacky programming
            ViewParent homeBtnContainer = homeBtn.getParent();

            // The home button is an ImageView inside a FrameLayout
            if (homeBtnContainer instanceof FrameLayout) {
                ViewGroup containerParent = (ViewGroup) homeBtnContainer.getParent();

                if (containerParent instanceof LinearLayout) {
                    // This view also contains the title text, set the whole view as clickable
                    ((LinearLayout) containerParent).setOnClickListener(dismissDialogClickListener);
                } else {
                    // Just set it on the home button
                    ((FrameLayout) homeBtnContainer).setOnClickListener(dismissDialogClickListener);
                }
            } else {
                // The 'If all else fails' default case
                homeBtn.setOnClickListener(dismissDialogClickListener);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Along with your comment it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298370/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-preferencescreen-android).

For the XML:

```
<Preference android:title="Acts like a button"
            android:key="button"
            android:summary="This will act like a button"/>
```

Then for the Java in your `onCreate()`

```
Preference button = (Preference)findPreference("button");

button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
    new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
            //code for what you want it to do   
            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the help and I have looked at that.  I do not think it is necessary to build my own layout, I just want the up button to appear on the preference screen.